# convert string array in java

Tags: java, android

I can convert an array like so:

```
String [] [] friend = new String [] [] {{{robert, marie}, {jhony, eva}, ​​{mike, laura}, ​​{adrian, rachel}, {kristen, anthony}};
```

CHOOSE two couples at random and the result is something like this:

```
String [] [] friend = new String [] [] {{{robert, marie}, {adrian, rachel}};
```

to later make so:

```
String [] friendfin = new String [] {{robert, marie, adrian, rachel}};
```

anyone can help me with this code please ... thanks

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
String[][] friends = new String[][]{
   {robert, marie}, {jhony, eva}, ​​{mike, laura},
   ​​{adrian, rachel}, {kristen, anthony}
};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String[] array : friends)
{
    for(String friend : array) list.add(friend);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
String[] friendfin = new String[list.length];
list.toArray(friendfin); // fill the array
friendfin = Arrays.copyOf(friendfin, 4);
```

Comment: @Aubin `list.addAll()` takes `Collection` not an array!